# Add a new column that will sum a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**dbo.table1**

```
DataID MemberID
2        1001
3         1001
```

**dbo.table2**

```
PointsID MemberID  PartnerPoints
1         1001     100
2         1001     100
```

**dbo.table3**

```
DataID table3ID PointsID    PartnerPoints
2        1        1             100
3        2        2             100
```

I need to add a new column on each table that will make the sum of partnerPoints column in dbo.table3 to 0.

Expected output:

**dbo.table1**

```
DataID MemberID
2        1001
3        1001
4        1001
```

**dbo.table2**

```
PointsID MemberID  PartnerPoints
1         1001     100
2         1001     100
3         1001     -200
```

**dbo.table3**

```
DataID table3ID PointsID    PartnerPoints
2        1        1             100
3        2        2             100
4        3        3             -200
```

I tried this

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table3]
(
    DataID
    PointsID
    PartnerPoints,
)
SELECT
   DataID
   PointsID
   -PartnerPoints,
FROM @tempTable t
    INNER JOIN dbo.table2 e ON t.memberID = e.MemberID 
WHERE e.PartnerPoints <> 0
```

instead of adding only one row in dbo.table3 it add 2 columns:

**dbo.table3**

```
DataID table3ID  PointsID    PartnerPoints
2        1        1             100
3        2        2             100
4        3        3             -100
4        4        3             -100
```

What part in the code do I need to improve? Using group by does not give the expected output.

Comment: What is the content of your temp table and how will this table be filled?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help.

I tried this.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table3]
(
    DataID
    PointsID
    PartnerPoints,
)
SELECT
   MAX(DataID)
   MAX(PointsID)
   -SUM(PartnerPoints),
FROM @tempTable t
    INNER JOIN dbo.table2 e ON t.memberID = e.MemberID 
WHERE e.PartnerPoints <> 0
```

output:
**dbo.table3**

```
DataID table3ID PointsID    PartnerPoints
2        1        1             100
3        2        2             100
4        3        3             -200
```

I don't used group by since it will only group it by  pointsID and dataID which results to inserting of 2 new rows in dbo.Table3 instead of 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table3]
(
    DataID
    PointsID
    PartnerPoints,
)
SELECT
   DataID
   PointsID
   SUM(-PartnerPoints),
FROM @tempTable t
    INNER JOIN dbo.table2 e ON t.memberID = e.MemberID 
WHERE e.PartnerPoints <> 0
group by DataID,PointsID
```